# simulation for hector slam in ground robot

Tags: ros, robot, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I want to run a simulation with hector slam in a ground robot (with laser, odom and imu). I want to use the final gridmap and the estimated robot position.

Anyone knows an alternative to  hector_quadrotor_demo but with a  ground robot?

many thanks,
Filipe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45128/simulation-for-hector-slam-in-ground-robot/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, there is a tutorial on setting up your robot for hector slam

check out  [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot)

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0